# All the ways to return 3 if you get 7 and vice versa – interview question

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

This is a question that I was asked in an interview:
Implement a function that gets an integer n and does the following:
1. if n is 3 -> return 7.
2. else if n is 7 -> return 3.
3. otherwise return any number you like (undefined behavior).

Also describe what's the runtime and space complexity of each way.

So first I gave the trivial way of using if-else statement - and said it's `O(1)` run-time + space complexity. Then the interviewer said: "what if you can't use if statements (including switch-case and other if statements similarities)?"

So I suggested using bitwise operations: `return n^=4`. Said that it's `O(1)` run-time + space complexity. Then the interviewer said: "what if you can't use bitwise operations?"

So I suggested using an array like this:

```
int mem[8] = {-1, -1, -1, 7, -1, -1, -1, 3}; 
return mem[n];
```

Said it's `O(1)` run-time + space complexity, how ever it might be non-efficient if we have large numbers instead of `3` and `7`.

Then the interviewer said: "what if you can't use arrays?" - and here I got stuck.

It seems like there is a fourth way... any suggestions?

Comment: Did the interview not ask `what if you can't use +,-,*,/,%`?

Comment: @vivek_23 lol, added 2nd solution without using math operation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

how about

```
def foo(n)
  return 10 - n
end


foo(3) => 7
foo(7) => 3
```

Answer (score 9):

How about this

```js
function myfunc(n) {
   return 21 / n
}

console.log(myfunc(7))
console.log(myfunc(3))
```

**UPDATE: #2 Solution**

```js
function myfunc(n) {
   return "37".replace(n, "")
}

console.log(myfunc(7))
console.log(myfunc(3))
```

Comment: Nice one , +1. However I have a preference for the subtraction way, since this one will cause an error when n is 0.

Comment: You're right.
Idk why did I think about division first rather than substraction lol

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius Nice +1.

Answer (score 3):

Another one is. `(n + 4) % 8`.

"All the ways" is surely infinite.

Answer (score 1):

**Memo Solution:**

```
function myFunc(x){
 const memo = {7:3,3:7}
 return memo[x]
}
console.log(myFunc(3))
console.log(myFunc(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

The fourth way:

```
def foo(n):
    return 10-n
```

1. For n=7, foo(7) returns 10-7=3.
2. For n=3, foo(3) returns 10-3=7.
3. For any other value of n, I can return any number I like, so I return `10-n`.

So, time complexity: `O(1)` and space complexity: `O(1)`.

Disclaimer: I'm not the interviewer. :P

Answer (score 0):

## XOR Solution

```js
function XorSolution(n) {
  return n^4
}

console.log(XorSolution(7))
// 3
console.log(XorSolution(3))
// 7
```

### Why does this work?

The truth table for XOR (Exclusive OR) is:

```
0^0 = 0
0^1 = 1
1^0 = 1
1^1 = 0
```

- 3 in binary is `011`
- 7 in binary is `111`
- 4 in binary is `100`

XOR is a bitwise operation (performed on each pair of corresponding bits)

So 3 XOR 4 is 7 because:

```
011
^
100
=
111
```

And
7 XOR 4 is 3 because:

```
111
^
100
=
011
```