# I need a function for putting 5 as argument and return 7 and vice versa

Tags: java, android

Make a method/function with one parameter/argument of int type. if user pass 5 value then it will return 7 and if user put 7 it will return 5 . but important thing is that I was not allowed to use any conditional operation like == , <, >, <=,  >=, if else, ternary operator ,switch statement , while, for loop and any built in method.

Comment: `public int fiveOrSeven(int x) { return x ^ 2; }`

Comment: please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523148/all-the-ways-to-return-3-if-you-get-7-and-vice-versa-interview-question

Comment: 4 + (x % 4), or (12-x)

Comment: Another modulus based solution 7-(v%5)

Comment: An arithmetic in Python 7-((v/2)-2)*2

Answer (score 6):

```
public int fiveOrSeven(int input){
    return 35 / input;
}
```

Comment: Oh this is so simple . My bad .

Comment: People, please stop upvoting. This can't be my highest upvoted answer.